# What's the default segment register when using square brackets to read values in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

As we all know, we can read the value of an address using square brackets in NASM, such as that:

```
mov esi,  [ebp +8]
mov edi, [var]   -->  (var is a variable)
```

Those values in square brackets represent the offset address, but when we read values using that format, we absolutely need a segment, whether we are in real or protected mode, so what's the default segment register that NASM uses? I know that Windows uses flat mode, but if I set different values to different segment register(cs, ss, ds, es, fs, gs), which segment register will NASM use? I guess it is `ds`, right? Is the segment register different when using different expressions in square brackets? Is the default segment register the same both in real and protected mode? Thanks.

Comment: It uses "no override". Which segment is used depends on the instruction, NASM has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default segment register is ds for all 'base registers' except

```
 mov esi, [ebp + 542] ; // uses ss:
 mov esi, [esp + 123] ; // uses ss: too
 mov eax, [eax + esp] ; // uses ds, because eax is the base 
                        // and esp is the scalable register (with scale==1)

 stosb   ;; uses es:
```

It's not the property of assembler, but of the processor. To override it, there's a one byte segment override prefix before the instruction.