# Commutativity of cpu registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

Is [ebp+eax]=[eax+ebp] ?

I was given this question in class and the professor asked us to search for the answer but I can't come across any resource in the net.

Comment: Check the Intel reference manuals.

Comment: You could just write a little program that uses both, assemble it, and look at the listing file output. If the code bytes output for the two statements are identical, then they `[eax+ebp] == [ebp+eax]`.

Comment: @JimMischel This is only a sufficient condition, it is not necessary.

Comment: Practically (i. e. under a flat-model OS), the same. Theoretically - no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try googling for default segment register.

`[ebp+eax]` uses the ss segment register, while `[eax+ebp]` uses ds.

However, i can't think of a good search term to use if you don't already know the answer.

Comment: Are you certain of that? Can you show me a reference, or show me the output from an assembler that proves the difference?

Comment: Quick google search produced http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Addressing/R77_0070_relative_segments.htm, which has an example of [ebp+edx] vs. [edx+ebp] at the bottom. Also, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827050/whats-the-default-segment-register-when-using-square-brackets-to-read-values-in

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try it?

```
mov ebx,[ebp+eax]
mov ebx,[eax+ebp]
```

then

```
nasm -o fun.o fun.s -f elf
objdump -D fun.o
```

and see what comes out.  then look at the intel reference manuals to compare the results to the nasm output